# Gstreamer and hlssink to display over http doesn't work

Tags: http, gstreamer, live-video

I used the below command using gstreamer. I see the generated files in the root but VLC crashes when I try to open the playlist.m3u8
The main goal is to live stream from webcam on firefox browser.

```
gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! openh264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink playlist-root=localhost location=C:/inetpub/wwwroot/hlssink.%05d.ts playlist-location=C:/inetpub/wwwroot/playlist.m3u8
```

also the video tag doesn't show the video streaming.

```
<video width="352" height="198" controls>
    <source src="http://localhost/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here ; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To make this playable in VLC (started on the same machine where your IIS server is) you will need to modify `hlssink playlist-root` parameter. It should be

`... ! hlssink playlist-root=http://localhost ...`

This will correctly set prefix URL part of TS segments inside HLS playlist

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:88
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:15

#EXTINF:15.026812553405762,
http://localhost/hlssink.00087.ts
#EXTINF:15.006274223327637,
http://localhost/hlssink.00088.ts
#EXTINF:15.011569976806641,
http://localhost/hlssink.00089.ts
#EXTINF:15.020917892456055,
http://localhost/hlssink.00090.ts
#EXTINF:15.016651153564453,
http://localhost/hlssink.00091.ts
```

and VLC player will know exact URL(s) to download segments from.

Unfortunately, **your HLS is not playable by (most of) browsers** because implementation of `<video>` tag does not support MPEG Transport Stream (MPEG TS) media container that your segments are packed in.

**To solve this**, you can use, for example, [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) library which will, among other things, transmux MPEGTS segments into MP4 container supported by standard HTML5 `<video>` tag.

Comment: I searched on google for more than a day straight and somehow this post and answer didn't come up at the top. I had VLC playing the hlssink stream successfully, but no browser was able. The explanation about the problems in the browsers with HLS and a link to hls.js library to solve that problem are exactly what I needed. Thanks for this info.